# Why are mutable values in Python Enums the same object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, identity

While experimenting with different value types for `Enum` members, I discovered some odd behavior when the values are mutable.

If I define the values of an `Enum` as different lists, the members still behave similarly to when the `Enum` values are typical immutable types like `str` or `int`, even though I can change the values of the members in place so that the values of the two `Enum` members are the same:

```
>>> class Color(enum.Enum):
        black = [1,2]
        blue = [1,2,3]  

>>> Color.blue is Color.black
False
>>> Color.black == Color.blue
False
>>> Color.black.value.append(3)
>>> Color.black
<Color.black: [1, 2, 3]>
>>> Color.blue
<Color.blue: [1, 2, 3]>
>>> Color.blue == Color.black
False
>>> Color.black.value == Color.blue.value
True
```

However, if I define the values to be identical lists, each member's value seems to be the same **object**, and thus any mutation of one member's value affects all members:

```
>>> class Color(enum.Enum):
        black = [1,2,3]
        blue = [1,2,3]

>>> Color.blue is Color.black
True
>>> Color.black == Color.blue
True
>>> Color.black.value.append(4)
>>> Color.black
<Color.black: [1, 2, 3, 4]>
>>> Color.blue
<Color.black: [1, 2, 3, 4]>
>>> Color.blue == Color.black
True
```

Why does `Enum` behave this way?  Is it the intended behavior or is it a bug?

**NOTE:** *I'm not planning on actually using Enums this way, I was simply experimenting with using non-standard values for Enum members*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#duplicating-enum-members-and-values):

> Given two members A and B with the same value (and A defined first), B is an alias to A. By-value lookup of the value of A and B will return A. By-name lookup of B will also return A:
>
> ```
> >>> class Shape(Enum):
> ...     square = 2
> ...     diamond = 1
> ...     circle = 3
> ...     alias_for_square = 2
> ...
> >>> Shape.square
> <Shape.square: 2>
> >>> Shape.alias_for_square
> <Shape.square: 2>
> >>> Shape(2)
> <Shape.square: 2>
> ```

This operates by equality, even when the values are mutable. Since you defined equal values for `black` and `blue`, with `black` first, `blue` is an alias for `black`.

Comment: It should have been plainly obvious in the second example when I got `<Color.black: [1, 2, 3, 4]>` as the `repr` for `Color.blue`...thanks!

Answer (score 5):

To complement [@user2357112's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40641327/4952130), take a look in `EnumMeta`, the metaclass for all `Enum` classes; it gets a peek at every class definition that has its type and gets a change to alter it.

Specifically, it takes care to  [re-assign members with the same value in its `__new__` method](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/enum.py#l167)  via simple assignment:

```
    # If another member with the same value was already defined, the
    # new member becomes an alias to the existing one.
    for name, canonical_member in enum_class._member_map_.items():
        if canonical_member._value_ == enum_member._value_:
            enum_member = canonical_member
            break
```

I didn't opt to check the docs and instead looked in the source. Lesson to take: Always check the docs, and if `ExplanationNotFound` is raised;  check the source :-)

Answer (score 4):

[From the Python documentation for Enums](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#how-are-enums-different):

> **By default, enumerations allow multiple names as aliases for the same value**. When this behavior isn’t desired, the following decorator can be used to ensure each value is used only once in the enumeration....

This means that `blue` is an alias for `black`. When either one changes, the other must as well.

You can however, force Python to make each enum value unique, by using the `enum.unique` decorator. Also from the docs:

> ```
> >>> from enum import Enum, unique
> >>> @unique
>  ... class Mistake(Enum):
>  ...     one = 1
>  ...     two = 2
>  ...     three = 3
>  ...     four = 3
>  ...
>  Traceback (most recent call last):
>  ...
>  ValueError: duplicate values found in <enum 'Mistake'>: four -> three
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Python 3 Enum class doesn't enforce uniqueness unless you specifically tell it to via the [unique decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#ensuring-unique-enumeration-values)

See also [duplicate values](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#duplicating-enum-members-and-values). since `blue` is identical to `black`, it just becomes an alias for `black`.

Comment: Useful comment, but a useful answer, IMO.