# Why are mutable values allowed in Python Enums?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, enums, hashable

This is somewhat of a follow on to [Why are mutable values in Python Enums the same object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40641213/why-are-mutable-values-in-python-enums-the-same-object).

If the values of an `Enum` are mutable (e.g. `list`s, etc.), those values can be changed at any time. I think this poses something of an issue if `Enum` members are retrieved by value, especially if someone inadvertently changes the value of an `Enum` he looks up:

```
>>> from enum import Enum
>>> class Color(Enum):
        black = [1,2]
        blue = [1,2,3]

>>> val_1 = [1,2]
>>> val_2 = [1,2,3]

>>> Color(val_1)
<Color.black: [1, 2]>

>>> Color(val_2)
<Color.blue: [1, 2, 3]>

>>> my_color = Color(val_1)
>>> my_color.value.append(3)

>>> Color(val_2)
<Color.black: [1, 2, 3]>

>>> Color(val_1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
ValueError: [1, 2] is not a valid Color
```

I think given normal Python idioms this is *okay*, with the implication being that users *can* use mutables as their `Enum` values, but just to understand the can of worms they might be opening.

However this brings up a second issue - since you can look up an `Enum` memeber by value, and the value can be mutable, it must be doing the lookup by a means other than a hashmap/`dict`, since the mutable cannot be a `key` in such a `dict`.

Wouldn't it be more efficient (although, granted, less flexible) to limit `Enum` values to only immutable types so that lookup-by-value could be implemented with a `dict`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears the answer to my second question was hiding in plain sight in the soure code for `enum.py`.

Each `Enum` *does* contain a `dict` of `value->member` pairs for *hashable* (i.e. immutable) values, and when you look up an `Enum` by value, it attempts to retrieve the member from that `dict`.  If the value is not *hashable*, it then brute-force compares for equality against all existing `Enum` values, returning the member if finds a match.  The relevant code is in lines 468-476 in `enum.py`:

```
try:
    if value in cls._value2member_map_:
        return cls._value2member_map_[value]
except TypeError:
    # not there, now do long search -- O(n) behavior
    for member in cls._member_map_.values():
        if member._value_ == value:
            return member
raise ValueError("%r is not a valid %s" % (value, cls.__name__))
```

So it appears as though the designers of `enum.py` wanted to have a quick lookup when getting `Enum`s by value, but still wanted to give the flexibility of having mutable values for `Enum` values (even though I still can't think of a reason *why* someone would want that in the first place).

Comment: Here\`s a use case for mutability: let\`s say the program has multiple exit codes comprising an enum and each of the codes has its own exit message (e.g. `CODE = [123, "Exit #123"]`). One of the exit cases is when the user calls the script wrong so you need to show the parameter reference. The problem is that the reference is encapsulated in an [`ArgumentParser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) object. So first you initialize the enum then execute several `add_argument()`-s, and then do something like that: `ExitCode.HELP.value[1] += '\n' + args.format_help()`. Voilà!

Comment: @hidefromkgb As far as I understand your example, it would work with a tuple.

Comment: one use case might be: ``` class Foo(Enum): NO_REPLY = {'name': 'Team Bar', 'email': 'no-reply@bar.com'} SUPPORT = {'name': 'Team Bar', 'email': 'support@bar.com'} ``` But I somehow feel that's not good, and am doing this instead: ``` class Foo(Enum): NO_REPLY SUPPORT ``` and then keeping a dictionary: ``` addresses = {Foo.NO_REPLY: {'name': 'Team Bar', 'email': 'no-reply@bar.com'}, Foo.SUPPORT: {'name': 'Team Bar', 'email': 'support@bar.com'}} ```

Comment: On second thought, I think I can actually use `enum` for my use case in a cleaner way using `namedtuple`:
```
Address = namedtuple('Address', ['name', 'email'])

class Foo(Enum):
 NO_REPLY = Address('Team Bar', 'no-reply@bar.com')
 SUPPORT = Address('Team Bar', 'support@bar.com')
```

Answer (score 2):

It's worth highlighting that enum values *can be anything* according to the documentation.

> Note Enum member values Member values can be anything: int, str, etc..
>   If the exact value is unimportant you may use auto instances and an
>   appropriate value will be chosen for you. Care must be taken if you
>   mix auto with other values.
>   https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#creating-an-enum

It's a pretty big departure from other enum entities in other languages. The allowance should make for some interesting possibilities however. I like the string as value variant where the source code friendly enum name is used in source while the enum value can serve for presentation purposes as in front-end code or console app help text or something.